# Java client PressKey Method works fine, but the key is not pressed in Mobile?

Tags: appium, java-client

I have this below snippet of code in my automation framework

```
 public void settings() {
        try {
            //((AndroidDriver) Driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.SETTINGS);
            ((AndroidDriver) Driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.SETTINGS));
            updateTestLog(Action, "settings pressed", Status.PASS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            updateTestLog(Action, ex.getMessage(), Status.DEBUG);
            Logger.getLogger(KeyActions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I have connected with the mobile and see if it's working fine. In Appium server got log traces that Key code 176 (Settings) worked fine. But no action in mobile screen

I have tried it for different keys like "Menu","home","search" and "enter". I see it is executed and working fine in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to open [Settings Menu](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings) I believe the best option would be calling [driver.startActivity()](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/StartsActivity.html#startActivity-io.appium.java_client.android.Activity-) function like:

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(new io.appium.java_client.android.Activity("com.android.settings",".Settings"));
```

If you're looking for a cross-platform solution it might be easier to go for [Launch command](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Launch) available via [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension)